# Append Camera Tracking to a new file

Tags: camera, tracking, append

I have done a camera track and saved the file.  In a new file I have created a model.  I want to append (or whatever) the camera move from the first to the second file and can't find the way.  I have tried appending and from object brought in the camera but it doesn't move in the second file.  Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: why don't you append your object to the file were you did your camera tracking?

Comment: Can you clarify: By camera track do you mean video tracked on the Video Clip Editor and then solved to a  3D scene, or a camera in the 3D environment that is tracking another object or following a track? Can you plase edit your question with more information, pictures or a blend file?